# Шлюз на Ubuntu 18.04.4 раздает ip адреса клиентам но не пускает их в интернет. В чем проблема?

Tags: ubuntu, сервер, маршрутизация

Интерфейсы:

enp3s5 - lan
enp3s6 - wan

Настройки шлюза:

```
1. Установил: Ubuntu Server 18.04.4 x64 [ MD5:5c43d0b0ade0b554c2d51c85e5f0095b ]
2. Установил: pppoeconf

3. Отключил и удалил netplan:

 sudo nano /etc/default/grub
 GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="netcfg/do_not_use_netplan=true" 

 sudo update-grub

 systemctl stop systemd-networkd.socket systemd-networkd
 networkd-dispatcher systemd-networkd-wait-online systemctl disable
 systemd-networkd.socket systemd-networkd networkd-dispatcher
 systemd-networkd-wait-online systemctl mask systemd-networkd.socket
 systemd-networkd networkd-dispatcher systemd-networkd-wait-online
 apt-get --assume-yes purge nplan netplan.io

4. Подключился к интернету:

 sudo pppoeconf
 reboot
 sudo pon dsl-provider

5. Сконфигурировал файл /etc/network/interfaces:

 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback

 auto ppp0
 iface ppp0 inet ppp
 pre-up /bin/ip link set enp3s6 up # line maintained by pppoeconf
 provider dsl-provider

 auto enp3s6
 iface enp3s6 inet manual

 auto enp3s5
 iface enp3s5 inet static
 address 192.168.2.1
 netmask 255.255.255.0

 post-up /etc/nat

6. Установил DHCP-server:

sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server

7. Сконфигурировал файл /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server:

 INTERFACESv4="enp3s5"
 INTERFACESv6=""

8. Сконфигурировал файл /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf:

 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;
 authoritative;
 log-facility local7;

 shared-network cable{

 subnet 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0{

 range 192.168.2.100 192.168.2.250;
 option domain-name-servers 77.88.8.7, 77.88.8.3; #YandexDNS / Safe search
 option routers 192.168.2.1;
 option time-servers 192.168.2.1;
 option broadcast-address 192.168.2.255;
 default-lease-time 600;
 max-lease-time 7200;

 }
 }

9. Запустил сервер:

 sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
 sudo service isc-dhcp-server status
 Active: active (running)

10. Сконфигурировал файл /etc/nat:

 #!/bin/bash

 modprobe iptable_nat
 modprobe ip_conntrack_ftp
 modprobe ip_nat_ftp
 modprobe ip_nat_pptp

 iptables -F
 iptables -F -t nat
 iptables -F -t mangle
 iptables -X
 iptables -t nat -F
 iptables -t mangle -F

 iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
 iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
 iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT

 iptables -A FORWARD -i enp3s5 -o ppp0 -s 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT

 iptables -A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o enp3s5 -d 192.168.2.0/24 -j ACCEPT

 iptables -P FORWARD drop

 iptables  -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.2.0/24 -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE

 route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev enp3s5
 route add -net 0.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.255 dev ppp0

 11. sudo chmod 755 /etc/nat


 12. /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward   1
 13  /etc.sysctl.conf     net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

DHCP сервер работает, выдает ip адреса клиентам, но не выпускает их в интернет. Почему?